# UCMA 5 NegotiateSecurityAssociation error when machine is not part of the domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ucma

I'm making my first steps in the UCMA world. The samples Microsoft delivers as part of the SDK seem simple enough, but I've hit a snag. If I run any of them from my dev box, I get an AuthenticationException when establishing the UserEndpoint.

The message of the exception is "Unable to perform authentication of credentials". Drilling down to the inner exception, I see this

NegotiateSecurityAssociation failed, error: -2146893039

My Skype 4 Biz pool is in a different domain than my dev box (in fact the dev box is not domain joined), the Skype4B domain CA is trusted though so the error comes somewhere later than in the establishment of a TLS session (initially I got a TLS error since the CA wasn't trusted).

Reading through the SDK documentation, in the chapter about activating trusted applications it is stated that unless you intent to run the Skype4B commandlets or use UCMA auto-provisioning, the machine running the app does not need to be a domain member. So now I'm thoroughly confused.. the same code works in the domain, but doesn't work on my dev box. It can't be a firewall issue because I run some of the clients in my skype4b domain in the same subnet as my dev box.

So what could I be missing?

Comment: Does the Skype4b Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing since you are talking about UserEndpoint's that you are just starting a simple user endpoint UCMA application and you are supplying the username/password to the UserEndpoint?

If that's the case then it's most likely the certificate presented by the Lync server is not trusted your non-domain joined machine.   You will need to manually add the root certificate that the Lync Server is using into the trusted cert store on your non-domain joined machine.  This is normally the root certificate used by the domain in general, which is why it works on domain joined machines as this certificate is added automatically.

Another test you should do is see if the Lync client runs and connects to the lync server from the non-domain joined machine.  My guess is that it will not as it will have the same certificate problem.

The Lync client / UCMA application errors around certificate failures are really bad and hard to understand!

Comment: Does the Skype4b Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Comment: I don't know specifically about android SDU, but if it's anything like the other sdk's No

Comment: I am asking abou skype4b sdk ?

Comment: I mean I need a custom Android Skype4B application, in which the user can set the media IP address which is sent in SDP messages. And, we'd have to implement a protocol to the Linux box, to tell it when media streams need to be opened/closed and to send INBAND Voice DTMF or send/receive INBAND RFC 2833 DTMF tones.

Comment: None of the Skypes client SDKs allow you to touch the SDP in any way.  UCMA allows you to add / handle / replace media types but not endpoint IPs.  If you really want to do want you want, you will have to use the Server SDK and create a SIP Proxy plugin that will change the SDP of the SIP packets you care about.  Other problems you may have: Support SRTP including SRTCP, support for ICE (Microsoft extensions) and TURN (Microsoft extensions) for external / federated connections.

Comment: Let me explain my question -The Android app could be a custom Skype for Business client made using the MS Android SDK, in which the SDP portion of the MSSIP message negotiates RTP media streams, that are sent to/received from a different IP address (of the Linux box). I need a custom Android Skype4B application, in which the user can set the media IP address which is sent in SDP messages. And we'd have to implement a protocol to the Linux box, to tell it when media streams need to be opened/closed and to send INBAND Voice DTMF or send/receive INBAND RFC 2833 DTMF tones.

Comment: If you want to interpret DTMF from a Skype endpoint (Android, whatever)?  Then your better creating a UCMA application that the skype endpoint calls and the UCMA application can interpret the DTMF and send them where ever you want.  If you want to "intercept" all DTMF between two endpoints (A calls B and C "intercepts" the DTMF) then this can't be done the way you want to do it.  In this scenario the only way is for you to be the man in the middle (B2BUA supporting media).  Microsoft don't provide any SDK to do this.  You either have to to it yourself or buy some thirdparty SDK to do it.

Comment: Support SRTP including SRTCP, support for ICE (Microsoft extensions) and TURN (Microsoft extensions) for external / federated connections. Do you think this Android - Linux architecture is practical, or just trouble?

Comment: so, the sdk does not deliver the functions we need. Where would we place the extra functions? On the Linux box?

Comment: I don't think we need to interpret DTMF except that if it's received as RFC 2833 packets, we need to convert the information to audible DTMF tones to be played into the room.A UCMA application is beyond the scope of what we're looking for.
I have an additional question. In the Microsoft's Skype for Business client, they implement some calendaring functions (meeting notifications, etc). Is that supported through the Android SDK? Or, is that implemented through some Outlook SDK?

Comment: Skype meetings can be accessed through the Microsoft Exchange Web SDK (EWS).  I'm guessing you could go through an outlook SDK but I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Let me check.

Comment: I don't think we need to interpret DTMF except that if it's received as RFC 2833 packets, we need to convert the information to audible DTMF tones to be played into the room.

Comment: @ShanePowell: Somehow I missed the notification on this one. My box does trust the domain CA, and the Skype4B Client does work on my box.